# Как без лишнего копирования обернуть вектор в optional и вернуть из функции? С++

Tags: c++, функции, vector, optional

Предположим есть какая-то такая функция:

```
std::optional<std::vector<MyType>> foo(AnyType any_argument) {

    std::vector<MyType> vec;

    /*do something*/

    if (false_statement) {
        return std::nullopt;
    } else {
        return ????????;
    }

}
```

В данном случае функция возвращает опшионал с вектором, либо, если что-то идет не так, пустой опшионал. Вектор формируется внутри самой функции в зависимости от аргументов. Как его правильно возвращать в данном случае? Если просто написать `return { vec };`, то по идее создастся опшионал с другим вектором и вектор из функции будет скопирован в вектор в опшионале. На данный момент я пишу `return { std::move(vec) };`, но мне не кажется это правильным вариантом. Есть ли другие способы вернуть этот вектор без лишнего копирования?

Comment: А по какой причине move не кажется правильным вариантом?) Move semantics для подобных целей и придумана, в целом

Comment: @ShamilMukhetdinov выглядит странно. Да и ощущение есть, что возможен некий более простой способ. Как будто костыль

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return { std::move(vec) };` (или `return std::move(vec);`) кажется нормальным вариантом.

Еще можно изменить тип переменной `vec` на `optional`, и делать просто `return vec;`.

Comment: А во втором предложенном вами случае разве не будет происходить копирование vec-опшионала в опшионал, который мы возвращаем? Ведь возврат из функции происходит по значению в данном примере. Или же компилятор это оптимизирует и вернет rvalue-ссылку на vec?

Comment: @ComeInRage Если компилятор справится с NRVO, то не будет ни копирования, ни перемещения. Если не справится, то автоматически будет перемещение.

Comment: Понял. А почему во втором случае будет перемещение? Ведь в `return vec;` мы по сути вызываем конструктор `std::optional(const std::optional&)`, который является конструктором копирования. Почему тогда перемещение?

Comment: @ComeInRage, в данном случае компилятор поймет, что нужно вернуть optional, далее "отработает" элизия копирования

Comment: @ComeInRage См. [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision): *"if the compiler cannot perform copy elision but the conditions for copy elision are met ... the compiler will attempt to use the move constructor even if the object is designated by an lvalue"* А вот этот condition: *"a return statement, when the operand is the name of ... object with automatic storage duration ... which is of the same class type ... as the function return type"*

Answer (score 0):

Перемещение вектора в возвращаемый опциональный объект - это, конечно, хорошо. Но по исходному коду меня смущает тот момент, что вектор создаётся и заполняется, несмотря на то, что в конечном итоге по условию он может быть просто отброшен в ветке, где возвращается `nullopt`.

Если создание и заполнение вектора можно отложить до момента, когда точно ясно, что его придётся вернуть, то искомая строка может выглядеть как-то так:

```
return {{el1, el2, el3}};
```

Где `elN` - элементы итогового вектора. В этом случае не будет даже перемещения вектора, он сразу создастся внутри возвращаемого `optional`.

Comment: Да, это хороший вариант, но в моем случае он невозможен. Как я и сказал, вектор создается в зависимости от пришедших аргументов. Он не может быть заполнен в return